# How read rotated barcode using ZXing.Net?

Tags: c#, zxing.net

[Image with barcode rotated 90 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rBkB.jpg)

My code:

```
    private static string GetBarcode(Bitmap btBitmap)
    {
        IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            TryInverted = true,
            Options =
            {
                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.CODE_39 },
                TryHarder = true,
                ReturnCodabarStartEnd = true,
                PureBarcode = false
            }
        };

        return   reader.DecodeMultiple(btBitmap)?.ToString(); 
    }
```

A null value is returned, but if you rotate 90 degrees, everything is read well.
What's wrong?

Comment: ig its because the library is designed to read horizontal barcode, but in the image you provided in vertical...

Comment: would you like if i send a method to rotate bitmap image and then read it? cuz i dont think theres any other way to accomplish without rotating

Comment: was sure that AutoRotate is an option that automatically determines the rotation ... Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MiXaiL can you try using `BarcodeReaderGeneric` instead of `BarcodeReader`?

Comment: @Enfyve, thanks for the advice, now I read about BarcodeReaderGeneric, unfortunately I have not heard anything about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
public string DecodeZXing(Bitmap bitmapImage)
{
    try
    {
        // create a barcode reader instance
        BitmapLuminanceSource source = new(bitmapImage);
        BarcodeReaderGeneric reader = new()
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            Options = new DecodingOptions
            {
                TryHarder = true,
                PureBarcode = false,
                TryInverted = true,
                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.CODE_39 }
            }
        };
        // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
        Result result = reader.Decode(source);
        // do something with the result
        return result != null ? result.Text : string.Empty;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception("Error al extraer string de código de barras", ex); }
}
```